# Changing windows stops working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, alt-tab

Sometimes alt-tab doesn't work after a fresh boot into my Windows 7 Pro x64 install. Clicking on the windows in the taskbar doesn't change window either, it just makes them flash as if they need attention. The only way I can change window in this state is by minimising everything so I can see the window I want, or using that godawful Win + Tab switcher.

Has anyone else experience this problem and have any solutions? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this before and it's a real pain! Often it's a program that's running that is hijacking this particular process in one way or another. My first port of call would to be to run MSConfig, remove all programs from start-up and see if the problem still occurs after a reboot, then add a few start-up applications at a time to see which one is the culprit.

Iffy problem for sure, but usually I find it's some rogue program not interacting with the desktop properly.

Comment: This is going to be fun considering the number of programs I have in startup! If I find out what program is the offender I'll report back.